# Can a Power Query get the M code of another query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Can a Power Query return the M code for another query? I'm not talking about manually selecting **Reference** or **Duplicate** or **Advanced Editor** from the Power Query editor. I want the result of Query2 to have the M code of Query1 (`let Source =...`) that is refreshable when Query1 changes.

In Excel, I can get the query code from VBA via `ActiveWorkbook.Queries(x).Formula` but then I have to load that to a table and pull it into a query, and then have to rerun the VBA every time a query is updated.

In Power BI, I can use DMVs to get the query code and even the dependencies.

```
select * from $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS;
select * from $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_EXPRESSIONS;
select * from $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_CALC_DEPENDENCY;
```

But in Power BI Desktop, to use the DMVs I have to connect to localhost:12345 with a random port number. As far as I know, there's no good easy, repeatable way to use DMVs against the current file opened in Power BI Desktop without manually updating the port # each time.

I can get a list of all the queries in the current file with `#shared` or better yet `#sections`, but these commands seem to return the result of the queries, not the query code itself.

Is there any way a query can get the M code of another query?

Comment: Once you have the code, what do you plan to do with it?

Comment: I'm wanting to create better documentation for complicated Excel files/PBI models that have 10+ queries. The first goal is to create a readable dependency tree. Second, I want a list of all input datasources and output tables. I'd prefer to have one code base for Excel and PBI, and to not be dependent on an XMLA endpoint or to have to use .pbip on the PBI side. I haven't designed the documentation yet, but I'm expecting to land the data in a table and process it in Python to create an html report where I'll have better control over formatting. I have something like this for DAX already.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could create a shared repository of M code and have every query just do a pull for latest version

```
let Source = Text.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\directory\MyMCode.txt")),
Results = Expression.Evaluate(Source, #shared)    
in Results
```

Comment: Interesting. That's a nice way to build a query library. I wish there was an opposite function to Expression.Evaluate. I need something that returns the raw expression before evaluation!

Comment: The raw expression is the contents of the text file

Comment: Raw expression of the queries in Power Query, not in a file like your example.